# GTA:SA not working on Wine

Tags: wine, games

I'm trying to install *Grand Theft Auto: San Andreas*, which I have on a USB flash drive, and when I try to launch the game with Wine, it launches fine. But when I move to the new game menu and start a new game the loading bar starts and it gets about 90% of the way there and then the game freezes and I have to wait for the "is not responding" message and force quit to close and when I close the game I'm greeted by this error message:

```
Unhandled exception: page fault on read access to 0x0323050c in 32-bit code (0x025daace).
Register dump:
 CS:0023 SS:002b DS:002b ES:002b FS:0063 GS:006b
 EIP:025daace ESP:0177f810 EBP:0177f81c EFLAGS:00010206(  R- --  I   - -P- )
 EAX:0323050c EBX:00119708 ECX:031117c0 EDX:00000000
 ESI:0323050c EDI:031117c0
Stack dump:
0x0177f810:  031117c0 031117c0 00119708 0177f848
0x0177f820:  025dabd8 0323050c 00b72f20 025df0ac
0x0177f830:  031117c0 026770c0 031117c0 0177f860
0x0177f840:  02643758 00000000 0177f86c 025df147
0x0177f850:  001197c8 026770c0 026770c0 031117c0
0x0177f860:  0177f878 0264380e ffffffff 0177f884
Backtrace:
=>0 0x025daace EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in modloader.asi (0x0177f81c)
  1 0x025dabd8 EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in modloader.asi (0x0177f848)
  2 0x025df147 EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in modloader.asi (0x0177f86c)
  3 0x025e2f6e EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in modloader.asi (0x0177f884)
  4 0x025eff6d EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in modloader.asi (0x0177fb90)
  5 0x025ee7bc EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in modloader.asi (0x0177fbb0)
  6 0x025ec01f EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in modloader.asi (0x0177fc04)
  7 0x025f052b EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in modloader.asi (0x0177fc24)
  8 0x025eeb52 EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in modloader.asi (0x0177fc54)
  9 0x025f11db EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in modloader.asi (0x0177fde0)
  10 0x025f0b48 EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in modloader.asi (0x0177fdf8)
  11 0x008246f1 in gta_sa (+0x4246f0) (0x0177ff20)
  12 0x7b468749 call_process_entry+0x18() in kernel32 (0x0177ff48)
  13 0x7b46cda3 ExitProcess+0x4646() in kernel32 (0x0177ffd8)
  14 0x7b46875a call_process_entry+0x29() in kernel32 (0x0177ffec)
0x025daace EntryPoint+0xffffffff in modloader.asi: cmpl $0,0x0(%esi)
Modules:
Module  Address         Debug info  Name (87 modules)
PE    230000-  260000   Deferred        eax
PE    370000-  381000   Deferred        vorbishooked
PE    390000-  399000   Deferred        ogg
PE    3a0000-  3e1000   Deferred        ginputsa.asi
PE    400000- 1577000   Export          gta_sa
PE   1ab0000- 1bb8000   Deferred        vorbis
PE   21f0000- 2227000   Deferred        gtasa.widescreenfix.asi
PE   2440000- 24a3000   Deferred        iii.vc.sa.limitadjuster.asi
PE   25d0000- 2682000   Export          modloader.asi
PE   2690000- 2b15000   Deferred        comctl32
PE   2b20000- 2ce9000   Deferred        setupapi
PE   2d00000- 2d41000   Deferred        salodlights.asi
PE   2f60000- 2f9a000   Deferred        silentpatchsa.asi
PE   2fa0000- 2fe9000   Deferred        skygfx.asi
PE   2ff0000- 2fff000   Deferred        wshps.asi
PE  10000000-10011000   Deferred        vorbisfile
PE  62800000-628e7000   Deferred        usp10
PE  639c0000-63b2e000   Deferred        winmm
PE  64b40000-64b81000   Deferred        shcore
PE  65200000-6574c000   Deferred        ole32
PE  65800000-65825000   Deferred        xinput1_3
PE  65880000-6588c000   Deferred        api-ms-win-core-sysinfo-l1-2-1
PE  65980000-6599c000   Deferred        version
PE  68c40000-68d5f000   Deferred        shlwapi
PE  6a900000-6a922000   Deferred        aclui
PE  6ba80000-6ba8b000   Deferred        api-ms-win-core-fibers-l1-1-1
PE  6c0c0000-6c107000   Deferred        imm32
PE  6e540000-6e54c000   Deferred        api-ms-win-core-synch-l1-2-0
PE  6e8c0000-6e8cc000   Deferred        api-ms-win-core-localization-l1-2-1
PE  6fdc0000-6fff1000   Deferred        rpcrt4
PE  71240000-714a8000   Deferred        kernelbase
ELF 7b400000-7b824000   Dwarf           kernel32<elf>
  \-PE  7b420000-7b824000   \               kernel32
ELF 7bc00000-7bd7f000   Deferred        ntdll<elf>
  \-PE  7bc30000-7bd7f000   \               ntdll
ELF 7c000000-7c005000   Deferred        <wine-loader>
ELF 7d1c5000-7d1e4000   Deferred        libgcc_s.so.1
ELF 7d1ff000-7d300000   Deferred        msvcr100<elf>
  \-PE  7d230000-7d300000   \               msvcr100
ELF 7d49a000-7d4e7000   Deferred        uxtheme<elf>
  \-PE  7d4b0000-7d4e7000   \               uxtheme
ELF 7d4e7000-7d4ee000   Deferred        libxfixes.so.3
ELF 7d4ee000-7d4fb000   Deferred        libxcursor.so.1
ELF 7d565000-7d591000   Deferred        libexpat.so.1
ELF 7d591000-7d5de000   Deferred        libfontconfig.so.1
ELF 7d5de000-7d61d000   Deferred        libpng16.so.16
ELF 7d61d000-7d6df000   Deferred        libfreetype.so.6
ELF 7d74c000-7d756000   Deferred        libuuid.so.1
ELF 7d756000-7d76b000   Deferred        libxi.so.6
ELF 7d76b000-7d770000   Deferred        libxcomposite.so.1
ELF 7d770000-7d77f000   Deferred        libxrandr.so.2
ELF 7d77f000-7d78b000   Deferred        libxrender.so.1
ELF 7d78b000-7d793000   Deferred        libxxf86vm.so.1
ELF 7d793000-7d798000   Deferred        libxinerama.so.1
ELF 7d798000-7d7b7000   Deferred        libbsd.so.0
ELF 7d7b7000-7d7bf000   Deferred        libxdmcp.so.6
ELF 7d7bf000-7d7ed000   Deferred        libxcb.so.1
ELF 7d7ed000-7d93c000   Deferred        libx11.so.6
ELF 7d93c000-7d953000   Deferred        libxext.so.6
ELF 7d953000-7da10000   Deferred        winex11<elf>
  \-PE  7d970000-7da10000   \               winex11
ELF 7da10000-7e44c000   Deferred        shell32<elf>
  \-PE  7da40000-7e44c000   \               shell32
ELF 7e44c000-7e46a000   Deferred        libz.so.1
ELF 7e482000-7e50a000   Deferred        dbghelp<elf>
  \-PE  7e4a0000-7e50a000   \               dbghelp
ELF 7e50a000-7e548000   Deferred        ws2_32<elf>
  \-PE  7e520000-7e548000   \               ws2_32
ELF 7e548000-7e6a3000   Deferred        gdi32<elf>
  \-PE  7e570000-7e6a3000   \               gdi32
ELF 7e6a3000-7e8e9000   Deferred        user32<elf>
  \-PE  7e6e0000-7e8e9000   \               user32
ELF 7e8e9000-7e9c6000   Deferred        msvcrt<elf>
  \-PE  7e910000-7e9c6000   \               msvcrt
ELF 7e9c6000-7ea4b000   Deferred        advapi32<elf>
  \-PE  7e9e0000-7ea4b000   \               advapi32
ELF 7eec3000-7eed8000   Deferred        libnss_files.so.2
ELF 7eed8000-7efdd000   Deferred        libm.so.6
ELF 7efdd000-7efe8000   Deferred        librt.so.1
ELF 7efea000-7f000000   Deferred        wow64cpu<elf>
  \-PE  7eff0000-7f000000   \               wow64cpu
ELF f7ae2000-f7ae8000   Deferred        libdl.so.2
ELF f7ae8000-f7cd5000   Deferred        libc.so.6
ELF f7cd5000-f7cf8000   Deferred        libpthread.so.0
ELF f7cf8000-f7cfe000   Deferred        libxau.so.6
ELF f7d10000-f7ed6000   Dwarf           libwine.so.1
ELF f7ed8000-f7f03000   Deferred        ld-linux.so.2
Threads:
process  tid      prio (all id:s are in hex)
0000000e services.exe
    00000022    0
    0000001c    0
    00000015    0
    00000010    0
    0000000f    0
00000011 plugplay.exe
    00000019    0
    00000018    0
    00000012    0
00000013 explorer.exe
    00000028    0
    00000027    0
    00000026    0
    00000014    0
0000001a winedevice.exe
    0000001f    0
    0000001e    0
    0000001d    0
    0000001b    0
00000020 winedevice.exe
    00000025    0
    00000024    0
    00000023    0
    00000021    0
0000002e (D) Z:\home\lachlan\Desktop\Grand Theft Auto San Andreas\gta_sa.exe
    ["Z:\home\lachlan\Desktop\Grand Theft Auto San Andreas\gta_sa.exe"]
    0000003d    0
    0000002f    0 <==
0000003e explorer.exe
    00000042    0
    00000041    0
    00000040    0
    0000003f    0
System information:
    Wine build: wine-4.18 (Staging)
    Platform: i386 (WOW64)
    Version: Windows 7
    Host system: Linux
    Host version: 5.3.0-19-generic
```

I am on Ubuntu 19.10 on a 64-bit laptop.

Comment: try and install and use lutris for wine here is the lutris page on gta sa https://lutris.net/games/grand-theft-auto-san-andreas/